# How can I avoid repeating elements that only change one thing in CSS?

Tags: css, vue.js, css-selectors

My code is this and I would like to know if there is any way to avoid repeating the elements and only change "rotate" which is what interests me.

I found online that you can use "Counter-increment" but I do not know how to implement it in my code

I use vuejs to not repeat 30 divs

```
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="circle-container">
                <div class="circle" v-for="i in 30"></div>
            </div>
        </div>




.wrapper {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }

    .circle-container {
        margin: 60px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .circle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .circle:nth-child(1) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(500%);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(500%);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(500%);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(500%);
        transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(500%);
        background: #42A5F5;
    }

    .circle:nth-child(2) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg) translateX(500%);
        -moz-transform: rotate(12deg) translateX(500%);
        -ms-transform: rotate(12deg) translateX(500%);
        -o-transform: rotate(12deg) translateX(500%);
        transform: rotate(12deg) translateX(500%);
        background: #ffe63d;
    }

    .circle:nth-child(3) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg) translateX(500%);
        -moz-transform: rotate(24deg) translateX(500%);
        -ms-transform: rotate(24deg) translateX(500%);
        -o-transform: rotate(24deg) translateX(500%);
        transform: rotate(24deg) translateX(500%);
        background: #ffe63d;    }
```

***Continue 30 times increasing 12deg***

Comment: share the HTML code also, the HTML structure will define how we should change the code not only the CSS, you are probably having a bad HTML structure making the CSS code complex

Comment: Vanilla CSS? Or do you have access to SASS or LESS. As I was going to answer, but was down voted as soon as I posted. :/ Lesson learned... I'll ask first next time ;)

Comment: CSS, but I can consider SASS or LESS if the answer helps me.

Comment: see my answer with scss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using scss with `@for`:

[See working code](https://jsfiddle.net/b9o8q76p/)

[See compile scss to css](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/720e7708f61b61c31a5465ef46253e2d)

```
   .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 30px auto;


.circle-container {
  margin: 60px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.7;

  background: #ffe63d;
}
}
@for $i from 1 through 30 {
    .circle:nth-child(#{$i}){
      transform: rotate($i *12deg) translateX(500%);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a custom mixin:

```
@mixin transform-rotate-translate($degrees, $percentage) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate($degrees) translateX($percentage);
  -moz-transform: rotate($degrees) translateX($percentage);
  -ms-transform: rotate($degrees) translateX($percentage);
  -o-transform: rotate($degrees) translateX($percentage);
  transform: rotate($degrees) translateX($percentage);
}
```

Now you can call it in any element:

```
.circle:nth-child(1) {
  @include transform-rotate-translate(0deg, 500%);
}

.circle:nth-child(2) {
  @include transform-rotate-translate(12deg, 500%);
}

.circle:nth-child(3) {
  @include transform-rotate-translate(24deg, 500%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your are using Vue.js to dynamically insert the div you can keep the CSS generic and rely on some inline style that you generate with the div. You can easily use a variable that you increment by `12deg` for each div.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.circle-container {
  margin: 60px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: rotate(var(--d,0deg)) translateX(500%);
  background: #ffe63d;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle-container">
    <div class="circle" ></div>
    <div class="circle" style="--d:12deg"></div>
    <div class="circle" style="--d:24deg"></div>
    <div class="circle" style="--d:36deg"></div>
    <div class="circle" style="--d:48deg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The hat(winter bash) so nice on your head :)

Comment: @לבנימלכה giving me a big head ;) waiting to get more :p